# Responsive website screenshot with Pageres with URLs from a text file

Tags: phantomjs, webpage-screenshot

I am trying to use pageres(https://github.com/sindresorhus/pageres) module to take screenshots of my website in different resolutions.

It works fine when I provide the URL and the size in command line but it doesn't work when I have my urls in a text file. It takes a screenshot of only the last URL in the file. I use the following command to run pageres:

```
pageres 640x768 < urls.txt
```

URLs in the text file are newline separated so they look like this:

```
http://www.yahoo.com
http://www.msn.com
http://www.apple.com
```

So it basically takes a screenshot of only apple.com and throws the error below for each of the screenshot above it.

The error I get is:

```
TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object <evaluating 'options.windowSize.width'>
```

and the file it points to is webshot.phantom.js line 13.

Am I running the command incorrectly or something? I use it the way it is mentioned on their site.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score -1):

It might have been a bug at some point, but it works fine in the latest version. Just tested.

Comment: I had to replace the new line character from **crlf** to **lf** in my urls.txt(since I am on Windows) file using Notepad++ to make it work.